# iPhone: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am playing a video in a view controller. When the user hits the hardware home button and the video is currently playing the app crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in the simulator.

I read that I should use the `applicationWillResignActive` message to stop the video from playing which should solve the crashing.  So I am trying to register for this notifcation with the notification center, but my selector never gets called.  What am I doing wrong?

The following code is in my media player view controller:

```
- (void) playMedia {    
    NSURL *mediaUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tmpFilePath isDirectory:FALSE];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaUrl]; 
    player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

    player.view.frame = self.view.frame;    
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    [player.moviePlayer play];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // never gets called!   
    NSLog(@"resign active");
    [player.moviePlayer stop];
}
```

Comment: While you're correctly passing `nil` for the `object` to `addObserver`, for future readers I'll note that if you supply something other than `nil` for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`, the `selector` may not get called.

Answer (score 7):

Note that if you have the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key set to true in your app's Info.plist, the `applicationWillResignActive` method is not called when the user hits the home button.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why that one isnt working for you, but im using

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopAction:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];`

with success in an Audio Player/Recorder.

possibly try implementing

`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
}`

in the app delegate and see if it calls.

Comment: Are you sure you need to register for these, at least in the app delegate?  I'm getting applicationDidBecomeActive without registering for it.  But I'm not getting any notifications when you press the Home button.

Comment: The delegate gets them automatically. Everyone else needs to register.