# From appdelegate, how to access ViewController's NSDate property in datePicker

Tags: swift, nsdate

in `ViewController`

```
@IBOutlet weak var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

in `AppDelegate`

```
let a = ViewController()

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    print(a.myDatePicker?.date)
}
```

I want to use the property `myDatePicker.date` from `ViewController` in `AppDelegate.swift`

but instance property value is `nil`
how do you access the real value in the `ViewController`'s `myDatePicker.date` which user picked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [view controller variables in ApplicationWillResignActive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222052/view-controller-variables-in-applicationwillresignactive)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of datepicker in userdefaults or appdelegates variable. and update it whenever any change occurs in Datepicker date.

So whenever applicationWillResignActive called then you can get the date from user defaults or Appdelagates variable.

Comment: How can I store the value of datepicker in appdelegate?

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15050028/4030948 to see how string is stored and get from Appdelegate Property, Same thing you can do by taking NSDate property type.